# Synax error in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to('Forside', '/startpages', html_options = {"class", (params[:controller] == "startpages") ? "menu-highlighted" : ""}) + " | " %>
```

Using `Rails 3.2.11`.

The error i m getting is

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
...ages', html_options = {"class", (params[:controller] == "sta...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{"class", (params[:controller] == "startpages") ? "menu-highlighted" : ""}
```

should be

```
{"class" => (params[:controller] == "startpages") ? "menu-highlighted" : ""}
```

Answer (score 1):

a simpler version for your `link_to`

```
= link_to('Forside', '/startpages', :class => ('menu-highlighted' if params[:controller] == 'startpages'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd argument is used as html_options by default. You dont have to use it in the link_to statement.